# Displaying PHP variable in a div

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem with displaying the input in a div in my calculator. It doesn't display anything. What am i doing wrong? I am pretty new to PHP, so please explain as much as possible, so that I could learn from this. If it is possible, then the variable should be constantly refreshed, so that it is always the latest input. This is my code, the problem can be found in the PHP part of the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>       
        <script src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="device">

            <div class="row">
                <div id="C" class="button">
                    C
                </div>

                <div id="MCR" class="button">
                    MCR
                </div>

                <div id="M+" class="button">
                    M+
                </div>

                <div id="M-" class="button">
                    M-
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="7" class="button" >
                    7
                </div>

                <div id="4" class="button">
                    4
                </div>

                <div id="1" class="button">
                    1
                </div>

                <div id="0" class="button">
                    0
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="8" class="button">
                    8
                </div>

                <div id="5" class="button">
                    5
                </div>

                <div id="2" class="button">
                    2
                </div>

                <div id="." class="button">
                    .
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="9" class="button">
                    9
                </div>

                <div id="6" class="button">
                    6
                </div>

                <div id="3" class="button">
                    3
                </div>

                <div id="=" class="button">
                    =
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div id="+" class="button">
                    +   
                </div>

                <div id="-" class="button">
                    -
                </div>

                <div id="x" class="button">
                    x
                </div>

                <div id="/" class="button">
                    /
                </div>

                <div id="display">
                        <?php 
                            var $input = "0";

                            function showInput()    {
                                echo $input;
                            };

                            while () {
                                showInput();
                            };
                        ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#device {
    width: 450px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #AB988B;
    margin: 150px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: solid 10px #B06A3B;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

#display    {
    width: 450px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #D4E7ED;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    top: 80px;
    left: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    color:  #B06A3B;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 75px;
}

.button {
    width: 65px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #7195A3;
    border: solid 2px #EB8540;
    color:  #B06A3B;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 75px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 17.5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: arial;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.row    {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/D9gWF/

Comment: JSFIDDLE is not working for php. use http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: You need to understand that PHP is a server-side language. As such, it does not work as you described. You are likely more interested in using a client-side language, such as JavaScript.

Comment: Your PHP code should be triggering at least one parse error. It seems you're confusing the several languages involved in web development. Have you actually installed PHP in your computer?

Comment: If you want dynamic effect you can't use php for this but javascript. And look at your php code it will loop forever.

Comment: IF you want constant update when clicking the buttons you can update `#display` with jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/D9gWF/1/

Comment: in php you don't need to use `var` when declaring variables. This will cause errors.

Comment: you also need to fix your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 
      $input = "0";

      function showInput($input)    {
          echo $input;
      };

      while () {
          showInput($input);
     };
 ?>
```

You don't use `var` when declaring variables in PHP. Just `$`. And learn about "scope". You were trying to use a variable you declared outside of the function, in the function. Which doesn't work. So in my code, I passed that variable as a parameter to be used inside the function.

I gave you a lot of key words and a basic explanation for you to do some more digging.

EDIT: And I don't think that `while` loop will do anything. While what? Something needs to go inside those parenthesis. What are you looping through?

Answer (score 0):

For PHP you need a php-enviroment like apache with php (for beginners: use "xampp")

this file needs normally the file-ending .php so the serverside-parser can parse your php-code in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have taken snippet from your code.

```
        <div id="display">
                <?php 
                    var $input = "0";

                    function showInput()    {
                        echo $input;
                    };

                    while () {
                        showInput();
                    };
                ?>
        </div>
```

Just change your code with mine below.

```
            <div id="display">
                    <?php 
                        $input = "0";
                        echo $input;
                    ?>
            </div>
```

Let me explain it.

```
$input = "0";
```

THe above line just initializing the value for our input variable, you can change 0 with any value you like.

```
echo $input;
```

This will echo out the value saved inside our input variable in first line of PHP code above. If you have declared another variable you can also echo that just change the variable name after $ sign. $ sign let the PHP know that its variable name starting up.

Answer (score 0):

Correct those parts into these and your code will work

```
            <div class="row">
            <div id="9" class="button">
                9
            </div>

            <div id="6" class="button">
                6
            </div>

            <div id="3" class="button">
                3
            </div>

            <div id="equal" class="button">
                =
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="plus" class="button">
                +   
            </div>

            <div id="minus" class="button">
                -
            </div>

            <div id="multiply" class="button">
                x
            </div>

            <div id="divide" class="button">
                /
            </div>

            <div id="display">
                <?php

                function showInput() {
                    $input = "0";

                    echo $input;
                }
               ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set an argument in the `while` loop. `While` what exactly? Also you need to look up variable scope. Functions can not access variables that are not contained within the function, in this case parse them in. eg

```
<?php
    $input = "0";

    function showInput($input)
    {
        echo $input;
    };

    showInput($input);

?>
```

Here is an example of your code working with my edits http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1nh-wda